# How to get consistent rule lengths for algorithmicx and listings floats?

Tags: formatting, listings, algorithmicx

In the following MWE, I would like **the rules** (the gray lines above and below the floats) **of both environments** (`listings` and `algorithmicx`, resp. `algpseudocode` style) **to have** visually (I'm not aiming for pt perfection) **the same indentation** relative to the line numbers and the text margins.

Personally, I prefer my current `listings` setting. So unless I unintentionally broke some typographic rule (no pun intended), I would like to make the `algorithmicx` float to conform to the code listing.

#### One picture says it all

[image]

#### MWE

Yes, it's a bit long...

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% algorithm settings
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@plainruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\rmfamily}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{{\color{gray}\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}}%
  \def\@fs@post{}%
  \def\@fs@mid{{\kern2pt\color{gray}\hrule height.8pt depth0pt\relax\kern\abovecaptionskip}}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
\makeatother
\floatstyle{plainruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\color{gray}\tiny#1}

% listings settings
\lstset{    
    numbers=left,numberstyle=\color{gray}\tiny,numbersep=1em,
    showspaces=false,showtabs=false,showstringspaces=false,
    frame=tb,tabsize=4,rulecolor=\color{gray},
    xleftmargin=1.5em,
    breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true
}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{K-Means algorithm}
\label{alg:k-means-orig}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State select $K$ observations randomly as initial cluster centroids
  \Repeat
    \State assign each observation to the closest centroid
    \State recalculate cluster positions
  \Until{cluster centroids do not move anymore}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={A blind text code listing},label={lst:blind}]
for(k=0; k<N; k++) {
    if(k%2=0) {
        tmp = foo[k];
        foo[k] = foo[k+1];
        foo[k+1] = tmp;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I produced an approximation with `\vspace{}`, `\hrulefill` and `\\`. It looks how I want it, but the magic numbers (`1.55em`, `-7pt`, `-9pt`) and the use of `\\` with negative spacing tell me that I'm doing it horribly wrong.

#### Result

[image: algorithm listing with roughly same top and bottom frame spacing as a listings code listing]

#### Changes

Replace the `%algorithm settings` part in the preamble with:

```
% algorithm settings
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@plainruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\rmfamily}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{{\color{gray}\hspace{1.55em}\hrulefill\\[-7pt]}}%
  \def\@fs@post{}%
  \def\@fs@mid{{\vspace{-9pt}\color{gray}\hspace{1.55em}\hrulefill{}\\[-6pt]}}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
\makeatother
\floatstyle{plainruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\color{gray}\tiny#1}
```